# Not able to delete Azure AD directory under my primary AD directory

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I had provided with Visual studio license subscription for azure services a few months back. I subscribed to the subscription with my official id (say A@mycompany.com) so i had default org (directory say D1) created with A@mycompany.com. Then i created another directory (org) along with D1 which is D2 (using the same subscription). I created D2 using az ad powershell as company don't provide employees the Azure AD access. My account A@mycompany.com enforced with MFA (auth app token based authentication) but D2 never had MFA requirement.
Now i had been away from Azure for last a few months but now when i am trying to login to porta.azure.com it routes me to D2 as a default directory and asks for MFA which i never set up for D2. Therefore i am not getting the auth token on my device / anywhere
I have been trying to sort this out through my company also but they are not getting any handle on my D2 directory under my subscription. So overall i am into Catch 22 situation.. can you please help how can this be sorted out? Really appreciate your help. thanks!!

Comment: Without changing the default directory to Tenant D1, you cannot login to Azure Portal. So, you can raise a support request  to Azure to delete the Tenant D2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without logging in to the portal, we cannot delete the default Azure AD Directory or change the default directory.

As MFA is enabled and you are not able to login to portal with the default Azure AD Directory, you cannot delete the Directory.

So in your case, you can raise a support request to the Azure Team to delete the Azure AD Directory

Comment: Thank you! it worked only with MS support ticket.

Comment: Glad to be of help